# insert from array has multi levels to database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have this array
how i can insert this data to database?
and how i can check if any item in array have [children]

i want to insert the data in database using

id, parent_id, level, order

note: some item has child item and some item don't have, and some child item have child
there is 7 level in my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 11
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: please show the database structure in which you wanna this array to be stored?

Comment: @Astha apparently one table with fields: id, parent_id, level, order

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion such as the following (I don't know what `order` is supposed to mean so it's left out).

```
function insert_array( $children, $parent_id, $level ){

    foreach( $children as $child ){
        insert_array_item( 
            $child, 
            $parent_id, 
            $level 
        );
    }
}

function insert_array_item( $item, $parent_id, $level ){

    //you need to get the $db here first

    $statement = $db->prepare( 
        "INSERT INTO `table` 
             VALUES (:id, :parent_id, :level )
        "
    );
    $statement->bindParam( ':id', $item['id'] );
    $statement->bindParam( ':parent_id', $parent_id );
    $statement->bindParam( ':level', $level );
    $statement->execute();

    if( isset( $item['children'] ) ){
         insert_array(
             $item['children'], 
             $parent_id = $item['id'],
             $level + 1
         );
    }
}

insert_array( $array, 0, 0 );
```